# Sequelize include nested realtion objects in a N:M -> 1:M assosiation

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 3 models Team Game and Stadium (each have 2 fields id and name)
I have a N:M realtionsheip between Team and Game

```
Team.belongsToMany(Game, { through: 'GameTeam ' });
Game.belongsToMany(Team, { through: 'GameTeam ' });
Game.hasMany(GameTeam , { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
GameTeam .belongsTo(Team);
Game.hasMany(GameTeam , { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
GameTeam .belongsTo(Game);
```

As an extra field to this relation I have an 1:M relation to GameTeam with Stadium

```
Stadium.hasMany(GameTeam );
GameTeam.belongsTo(Stadium);
```

When I try to include all models with findByPk using "include" I cannot get also the entire Stadium object but only the Id:

```
const getTeamById = async (teamId) => {
  return await Team.findByPk(teamId, {
    include: [
      {
        model: Game,
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
};
```

The result is:

```
Team:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Lyon",
    "games": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "game1"
            "gameteam": 
                {
                "teamId": 1,
                "gameId": 1,
                "stadiumId": 1
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to include inside gameteam team, game and stadium objects and not only the Ids
Any way to do it ?

**Update**
Ok, let me simplify it:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html
Section: Specifying attributes from the through table

> ```
> // User.findOne({ include: Profile })
> {
>   "id": 4,
>   "username": "p4dm3",
>   "points": 1000,
>   "profiles": [
>     {
>       "id": 6,
>       "name": "queen",
>       "grant": {
>         "userId": 4,
>         "profileId": 6,
>         "selfGranted": false
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

I don't know how to include inside "grant"  also user and profile and not only Ids

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any chance that a number of teams in a certain game could be other then 2?

Comment: You are right it's not a good example, I just replace my object names with example names from docs. Even though this, the problem to include in one findByPk also the objects from "gameteam" and not only ids still remains.....

Comment: I suppose you need to include the junction table `GameTeam` explicitly instead of `Game`